# SwiftUI Picker Help -- Populating picker based on the selection of another picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I am trying to populate a picker based on the selection of another picker. I am new to Swift and have been beating my head on this for way too long. I am sure its not as difficult as I am making it but I would appreciate any assistance.

I think my biggest issue is passing the selection of the first picker to the array name of the second. I have used switch case, tried to pass the selection raw value...etc. Below is a sample of what I would like it to look like without the binding of the pickers. Thanks

```
import SwiftUI

struct veggie: View {
    let veggies = ["Beans", "Corn", "Potatoes"]
    let beanList = ["Pole", "String", "Black"]
    let cornList = ["Peaches & Cream", "Sweet"]
    let potatoList = ["Yukon Gold", "Idaho"]
    @State private var selectedVeggie = "Bean"
    @State private var selectedBean = "Pole"
    @State private var selectedType = ""
    
            var body: some View {
                NavigationView{
                    VStack{
                        Form{
                            Picker("Please choose a veggie", selection: $selectedVeggie)
                                {
                                ForEach(veggies, id: \.self) {
                                    Text($0)
                                }
                            }
                            Text("You selected \(selectedVeggie)")
                            Picker("Type", selection: $selectedBean)
                                {
                                ForEach(beanList, id: \.self) {
                                    Text($0)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }     .navigationTitle("Veggie Picker")
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm imagining that you want this to be somewhat dynamic and not hardcoded with `if` statements. In order to accomplish that, I setup an `enum` with the veggie types and then a dictionary that maps the veggie types to their subtypes. Those look like:

```
enum VeggieType : String, CaseIterable {
    case beans, corn, potatoes
}

let subTypes : [VeggieType: [String]] = [.beans: ["Pole", "String", "Black"],
                                         .corn: ["Peaches & Cream", "Sweet"],
                                         .potatoes: ["Yukon Gold", "Idaho"]]
```

Then, in the view, I did this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedVeggie : VeggieType = .beans
    @State private var selectedSubtype : String?
    
    var subtypeList : [String] {
        subTypes[selectedVeggie] ?? []
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Form{
                    Picker("Please choose a veggie", selection: $selectedVeggie)
                    {
                        ForEach(VeggieType.allCases, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0.rawValue.capitalized)
                        }
                    }
                    Text("You selected \(selectedVeggie.rawValue.capitalized)")
                    Picker("Type", selection: $selectedSubtype)
                    {
                        ForEach(subtypeList, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0).tag($0 as String?)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }     .navigationTitle("Veggie Picker")
        }
    }
}
```

The `selectedVeggie` is now typed with `VeggieType`. The `selectedSubtype` is an optional `String` that doesn't have an initial value (although you could set one if you want).

The first picker goes through all of the cases of `VeggieType`. The second one dynamically changes based on the computed property `subtypeList` which grabs the item from the `subTypes` dictionary I had made earlier.

The `tag` item is important -- I had to make the tag `as String?` because SwiftUI wants the `selection` parameter and the `tag()` to match exactly.

---

Note: you say you're new to Swift, so I'll mention that you had named your view `veggie` -- in Swift, normally types have capital names. I named mine `ContentView`, but you could rename it `VeggieView` or something like that.

Comment: jnpdx, Thanks so much for this. Thanks for the code and the explanation. The tag item is what kept hanging me up. I never could get the selection parameters to match. This really helps me understand a little more of this language.

Comment: Also thanks for the heads up on the type naming. I knew that but your comment reiterates the importance of structure and syntax in our code even if it is just throwing up an example. Thanks again.